# Uncaught ReferenceError: MapWidget is not defined

Tags: python, openlayers, geodjango

I'm trying to create a form usefull to add only one single point on a map, I'm doing this for the first time. I use GeoDjango from Django 2.2 and OpenLayers 5.

I've created a simple model with only two field: name and point.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
from django.db import models

class AddPoint(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    point = geomodels.PointField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

The model is used from this form:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.gis import forms

class AddPointForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "type": "text",
                "class": "form-control form-control-lg",
                }
            ),
        )
    point = forms.PointField(
        widget=forms.OSMWidget(
            attrs={
                'map_width': 800,
                'map_height': 500,
                }
            ),
        )

    class Meta:
        model = AddPoint
        fields = []
```

I use this view to add a point on a map:

```
def addPointOnMap(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        geoform = AddPointForm(request.POST or None)
        if geoform.is_valid():
            new_point = geoform.save()
            new_point.save()
            return redirect('add_points_map')
    else:
        geoform = AddPointForm()
    context = {
        'geoform': geoform,
        }
    template = 'maps/editing/add_point.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

With the help of the standard form template I will add the informations on my map:

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ geoform.as_p }}
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-md-auto">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info shadow" value="Pubblica">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The problem is that I see this error when I go at the form's url:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MapWidget is not defined

Where I must define this widget? I'm a beginner, this thing for me is not clear.

In the page source I see that is automatically created this:

```
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="nxbLkfPnrPsXeJAO3MvKSDrNhGJMdcry62d1fzYtDBXtwe1iabFc0vZrlupbJGr2">
    <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-lg" maxlength="100" required id="id_name"></p>
<p><label for="id_point">Point:</label> <style type="text/css">
    #id_point_map { width: 800px; height: 500px; }
    #id_point_map .aligned label { float: inherit; }
    #id_point_div_map { position: relative; vertical-align: top; float: left; }
    #id_point { display: none; }

</style>

<div id="id_point_div_map">
    <div id="id_point_map"></div>
    <span class="clear_features"><a href="javascript:geodjango_point.clearFeatures()">Cancella tutti gli oggetti</a></span>

    <textarea id="id_point" class="vSerializedField required" cols="150" rows="10" name="point"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map_options = {};

var base_layer = new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()});

        var options = {
            base_layer: base_layer,
            geom_name: 'Point',
            id: 'id_point',
            map_id: 'id_point_map',
            map_options: map_options,
            map_srid: 3857,
            name: 'point'
        };

options['default_lon'] = 5;
options['default_lat'] = 47;
options['default_zoom'] = 12;

        var geodjango_point = new MapWidget(options);
    </script>
</div></p>
    <hr>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
      <div class="col-md-auto">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info shadow" value="Pubblica">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An user on Facebook give me a solution: I've miss `{{ geoform.media }}` in the head of the form's page.